# Location allocation in ArcGIS with an impedance parameter returning 'invalid impedance transformation type'?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, location-allocation

I'm attempting to run a location-allocation analysis in the entire US using ArcMap 10.6. The demand points are zip code centroids, that have been loaded using Load Locations with two additional properties: Weight = Income and ImpedenceParameter = UrbanicityTravelTime.

Facilities have been loaded as is (points only). When running the location allocation **minimize facilities**, I tried to select power/exponential as the impedence transformation but I'm getting an error: "invalid impedence transformation type" when clicking 'Solve'. I assume this is the only way as in the ESRI documentation it states that Linear transformation [ignore](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-network-analyst/locationallocationsolverproperties.htm) the impedenceTransformation parameter:

*Demand points have an ImpedanceParameter property, which, if set, overrides the Impedance Parameter property of the analysis layer. You might determine that the impedance parameter should be different for urban and rural residents. You can model this by setting the impedance transformation for the analysis layer to match that of rural residents and setting the impedance transformation for the demand points in urban areas to match that of urbanites*.

Does anyone know how to apply an impedence parameter (in this case, *individual* travel time for each of the demand points, essentially 5 different values based on the urbanicity of each point, with rural population willing to travel more to each facility)?

Comment: What value are you setting for the impedance parameter?

Comment: The values are 10,15,20,25, or 30 (travel time in minutes), that are based on the urbanicity for each zip code centroid.